# getting error enabling systemctl service on ubuntu machine

Tags: systemd

My systemctl service shows disabled. I want my service start on its own after a reboot.

```
service mongoport status
● mongoport.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongoport.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
```

I tried enabling the service getting this error, is there something I'm missing out here before enabling the service.

```
systemctl enable mongoport.service
Synchronizing state of mongoport.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable mongoport
update-rc.d: error: mongoport Default-Start contains no runlevels, aborting.
```

Comment: How did you install mongodb?

Comment: apt install <mongodb agent>